# Why is php array_unique($array); producing duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have a php function I'm trying to make efficient as possible, but there are redundancies I cannot get rid of. So I need some help.

Here's the actual code if you would like to take a look

```
function array_tags( $classes, $item, $args ){
if ( 'themes' === $args->theme_location ) {
    $tagsString = "";
        //cannot have spaces!!!!! change the page_title for something else
        $cat = get_queried_object();
        $catSlug = $cat->slug;

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'product_cat' => $catSlug,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                global $product;   

                   $tagsString .=  strip_tags($product->get_tags()) . ", ";    
                endwhile;
            } else {

            }
            wp_reset_postdata(); 


            $arr_tags = explode( ", ", $tagsString ); 

    var_dump(array_unique($arr_tags));
    if( !in_array($item->title, array_unique($arr_tags)) ){
        $classes[] = "not-the-droid-you-are-looking-for";
    }
    else{

    }
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'array_tags', 10, 3);
```

### here is the output for `var_dump($arr_tags);`

```
array(12) { 
    [0]=> string(20) "Discover your Wonder" 
    [1]=> string(3) "web" 
    [2]=> string(6) "aliens" 
    [3]=> string(9) "astrology" 
    [4]=> string(16) "celestial bodies" 
    [5]=> string(20) "Discover your Wonder" 
    [6]=> string(5) "humor" 
    [7]=> string(9) "mythology" 
    [8]=> string(7) "science" 
    [9]=> string(5) "space" 
    [10]=> string(20) "Discover your Wonder" 
    [11]=> string(0) "" 
} 
array(12) { 
    [0]=> string(20) "Discover your Wonder" 
    [1]=> string(3) "web" 
    [2]=> string(6) "aliens" 
    [3]=> string(9) "astrology" 
    [4]=> string(16) "celestial bodies" 
    [5]=> string(20) "Discover your Wonder" 
    [6]=> string(5) "humor" 
    [7]=> string(9) "mythology" 
    [8]=> string(7) "science" 
    [9]=> string(5) "space"
```

and so on, why does var_dump on $arr_tags produce multiple arrays?

### also, here is the `var_dump($tagsString)`

```
string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, "
```

### here is the output of `var_dump(strip_tags($product->get_tags()));`

```
string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, "
```

### here is the output of `var_dump((string)strip_tags($product->get_tags()));`

```
string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, " string(25) "Discover your Wonder, web" string(91) "aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space" string(20) "Discover your Wonder" string(142) "Discover your Wonder, web, aliens, astrology, celestial bodies, Discover your Wonder, humor, mythology, science, space, Discover your Wonder, "
```

Comment: Or a typo, I guess it should be $tagsString = "cats, dogs, dogs, dogs";

Comment: Have you tried testing a simple string/array instead of an array of 1000 items?

Comment: @ChrisHaugen [Even so, can't reproduce your problem](https://eval.in/454888).

Comment: Obviously, there is some piece of code missing if your result is that one. If you can't show it entirely, I suggest you review what's going on.

Comment: Well, I just replaced the example with the real code, if you'd like to take a gander at it

Comment: Instead of `var_dump(array_unique($arr_tags));`, try `var_dump($arr_tags);` and show us a chunk of repeated values.

Comment: @PaulCrovella he tried, actually... but couldn't. Check the review historic.

Comment: Ok i edited the question. So, the string `$tagsString` get exploded, but why does the exploded array create multiple arrays? shouldn't explode create one single array containing all the string items?

Comment: It seems you're trying to manipulate a multidimensional array as a flat array, and might be why `array_unique` is not working.

Comment: That's what I'm seeing, however, I think it is caused by the variable `$tagsString` each concatenation to it inside the while loop is creating a new string instead of adding the text to the existing string. Do you know of a way to add on to $tagsString's existing string instead of creating a new string?

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce, again](https://eval.in/454900). Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, you're right. What `strip_tags($product->get_tags())` is returning you?

Comment: I'm editing the question with tht info

Comment: Which is what you wanted, that's why I've formatted it, to be sure it wasn't the code logic, but pure data fault. Your concatenation doesn't seem wrong, however. Try casting it as string >> `(string)strip_tags($product->get_tags())`

Comment: Thank you, for all the help, by the way :) I posted the output you requested

Comment: Now, the question would be, how to turn all those strings into a single string, right?

Comment: I never saw a single non-object/array variable being set with multiple data

Comment: Anyway, try the casting thing I've said, see what you get. `(string)strip_tags($product->get_tags())` add the data type inside round brackets to force its type.

Comment: I've edited the comment.

Comment: Ok, I did that and added it to the quesiton, it looks exactly the same, though. Also. I tried doing .join to the array to convert it back to a string, it did the same thing.

Comment: Do you know what I think you should do? You should open another questions, asking why your **single** variable has **multiple** repeated data, because I couldn't figure it out so far and it seems to be the core of your issue. Use our discussion and your edited question as material.

Answer (score 1):

Your tagsString has syntax error you are not concating string instead your are just using "," .
Here is working code of your

```
<?php
$tagsString = "cats, dogs, dogs, dogs";
$array_tags = explode(", ", $tagsString);
$unique = array_unique($array_tags);
print_r($unique);
```